# Websocket (Node.js / Socket.io) Latency & Scaling in the Cloud

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, socket.io

we have developed a collaborative node Application, where Users interact in realtime within websocket driven world instances.

Actually the websocket Server is hosted with ec2 at amazon, using their autoscale feature to create new instances automaticly when required.

Static assets are served by Nginx and Cloudfront (S3).

Our Application is multi-language and should serve Users in the whole world with low latency.
Thats where it comes to problems...

Lets say we have 2 Users, one is located at Hawaii, the other one in Germany.
Both users enter the same collaborative instance located at ec2 Ireland.

The User from Germany gets a very low latency, while the User Hawaii gets almost 300ms what leads to serious issues, because our app really needs a good connection.

I did read alot about how to scale Socket.io, but the recommented solutions such as Nginx proxies and Redisstore wont solve the Network issues we actually have in such a case.

Maybe someone knows a solution to solve our problem?

Thanks

Comment: A "good connection" and a "low latency connection" are not necessarily the same thing.  Do you have a problem with the latency (lags in the user experience) or do you have a problem with packet loss and connection stability?  Does "collaborative instance" imply that these two users are interacting with each other?  Is your entire cluster running in Ireland, or was that just an example?  The problem needs to be clearly identified before a solution can be suggested.

Comment: Our application is a game where 30 users are collaborating within each server instance. The cluster is actually in Ireland, yes. Just static files are served over Cloudfront. We dont have problems with lost packages, but the latency variates between 40ms and 280ms, depending on the users location.